# How to write the code to get the required output

Tags: python, indentation

I need to write the code so that I get the required output (see image). When I run the code it doesn't show anything on the screen.

```
  word = 'Python'
  print("The original string is = ",end = '')
  for ch in word : # ch will take each character from name
  print(ch , end = ' ')
  print("\n")
  length = len(word) # len is function to give no. of characters
  print("The reversed string is = ",end = '')
  for ch in range(-1, (-length - 1), -1) :
  print(word[ch], end = ' ')![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSYlP.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehkHl.jpg)
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], for a start. Also, don't use pictures when all they contain is text. Rather, extract a [mcve] from your code and include both the actual and expected output it produces. Note that above code doesn't run in Python, because it lacks proper indentation.

Comment: Try to do the right format - `indent`.

Comment: Can someone show me the code cause I still can't do it right

Comment: Your code would work fine _with proper indentation_. https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you expect:

```
word = 'Python'
print("The original string is = ",end = '')
for ch in word : # ch will take each character from name
    print(ch , end = ' ')
print("\n")
length = len(word) # len is function to give no. of characters
print("The reversed string is = ",end = '')
for ch in range(-1, (-length - 1), -1) :
    print(word[ch], end = ' ')
```

Please read this to understand how to fix the indentation.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Answer (score 0):

```
word = "Python" 
stringlength=len(word) 
slicedString=word[stringlength::-1]
print ("The original string is =",word)
print ("The reversed string is =",slicedString)
```